# How do I modify a variable specified by the user?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to be able to change a variable based on user input, but I don't want to use `if`/`else` statements. I'm using a lot of variables in my actual code. Is there any way to change a variable from input alone?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 0;
int b = 0;

string input;

int main() {
    cin >> input;
    *variable specified by input variable* = 1;
}
```

Comment: @MaxLanghof Good point. After the coffee break, I'd still suggest a container (the variables in OP's code are of the same type, anyways).

Comment: Not without some kind of string-to-variable mapping structure. The way to create this structure that is best-suited depends on your specific needs and constraints.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an associative container to map the input to the variable. An example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int*> vars = {
    {"a", &a},
    {"b", &b},
};

// the assignment
*vars.at(input) = 1;
```